# How do you clear an SKCanvasView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I was looking at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129113/clear-the-drawings-in-skcanvas-skiasharp-in-xamarin-forms but I do not understand their solutions for how to clear the canvas. Can you guys please help me with how to clear the SKCanvasView with a button press? Thank you.

Comment: you clear it by NOT drawing anything when OnCanvasViewPaintSurface is called

Comment: If there is something let behind, then you can force it to clear the memory with the `Clear(SKColor)` method. But, as @Jason said, you don't "clear" a canvas, you just don't draw on it.

Comment: Thank you guys but I figured it another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the canvas I did the following code below:

```
private void OnClear()
        {
            inProgressPaths.Clear();
            completedPaths.Clear();
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
```